# PHP: Set duration before commenting again

Tags: php, comments, limit

I made a comment section for my project. But it lacks some 'security' I guess?

1) I can comment as many as I want. 
2) Similar comment is not disabled.

I'm wondering if there is such a thing in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You must be saving comments in database. If the rows areduplicate, You can add unique index like this

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE comments ADD UNIQUE INDEX comment_name (id, name );
```

Comment: This works, yes, but is a hack and not a proper thing to do in terms of a good software developement. If this is implemented, it should be really well and clearly documented.

Comment: The other way might to set up a cron job against the table to check for the duplicate and flush them off if they are :)

Answer (score 1):

1) If you have the date/time value saved in the database you can validate if the time of "when your last comment was" and the actual time, when the user try to add a new comment.

But if you want to add this validation in the presentation, you can hide/disable the section for a time and show/enable this section.

2) If you want to avoid duplicate entries in the comments sections, validate if the content or the title is not the same to the database.

I think when you do the first validation  (if the time is 5 seconds for example) and it's right to comment again, then you validate if the comment is the same.

Answer (score 0):

For your code that processes a comment and inserts it into the database, you should add checks to (a) see if that same person commented within the last X minutes, or (b) see if there is a similar comment.

(a) is pretty easy to implement. I'm assuming here that you are storing comments in your database with a column for `user_id` and a column for `timestamp`. Then you can just run a query to see if that user already left a comment within the time limit (let's set it to two minutes for this example.)

```
SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `user_id`='{$user_id}' AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MINUTE) < `timestamp`
```

If you run that query and it returns a row, then you know that user left a comment less than two minutes ago.

---

(b) Is more difficult, if for nothing else than the fact that you didn't really specify what it means for a comment to be "similar". You can check for similarity in the text either with keywords or with a string comparison function like Levenshtein. You would follow the same logic as in (a), just run a database query to check for similarity and report an error if necessary.

If you don't find any rows that match the above checks, then you can safely insert the comment into your database. Otherwise, you can report an error to the user, or however you want to handle it.

If you go into more specifics I'm sure someone could help you further.

Comment: Thank you jraede, your explanation gave me the picture \o

Answer (score -1):

You need to implement such a thing yourself. You might want to use PHP sessions for that.

Comment: Why the -1? With all that information in the question this is a proper answer.

Comment: I haven't done the downvote. But this is not answer, it should be comment. And you have that much of rep to put comment in question.

Comment: The question was, quoting: "I'm wondering if there is such a thing in PHP."

Comment: @Lasse: So why didn't you make your answer just `No`? Add some text. Explain what OP should take into consideration and possibly a brief rundown of what the code should look like.

Comment: :? I apologize for the grammar thingy. I don't really know how the specific words for specific things in programming.
I have limited knowledge of these things. I know I'm writing this in a textarea, and the button next to it is 'button'? 
Is there a dictionary site for all the buttons/textbox/etc in HTML?
Cheers! \o